# Prevent .lastChild from returning a carriage return?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get the first and the last node of a given element.

```
document.getElementById('test').firstChild
document.getElementById('test').lastChild
```

http://codepen.io/FezVrasta/pen/gaPJXe

The problem is that the lastChild function return me just a carriage return instead of the last useful node.

What is the best way to return me the last element or text node excluding the carriage return?

Comment: Try removing all whitespace between the child elements within `test`

Comment: I can't edit the source, I must use javascript.

Comment: If you want the last element, and not the last child (if that child can be a text node) then loop backwards over all the children until you find one that is an element.

Answer (score 5):

`lastChild` and `firstChild` return the first and last child nodes of the element, that can be an element, a text node or a comment. If You want to get the first and last child elements you can use:

```
document.getElementById('test').firstElementChild
document.getElementById('test').lastElementChild
```

it should be supported in all modern browsers

Comment: Had no idea that existed... although if you need to support IE8 and below (yes I know, but some of us still do unfortunately) it won't work

Comment: Thanks but I'm more looking for a way to get the lastChild excluding the carriage returns, I want even the text nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Go through the `previousSibling`s until you find one that is an element node.

The `nodeType == 1` means it's an element node... see [documention for all types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType)

```js
var lastElement = document.getElementById('test').lastChild;
while (lastElement != null && lastElement.nodeType != 1) {
  lastElement = lastElement.previousSibling;
}
if (lastElement != null) {
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = lastElement.id;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <div id="div1">a</div>
  <div id="div2">b</div>
  <div id="div3">c</div>
  <div id="div4">d</div>
</div>
<div id="output"></div>
```